# Including Firebase token in getting data from cloud firestore

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

In my Flutter application, I chose to use firebase cloud firestore instead of realtime database approach. I succeeded in writing codes for CRUD without making http requests. I am struggling on how to include the userId and userToken created when a user logs in since I don't have a url used in my code. Without the token, I am unable to get product items from the database  given the rules that require a user be logged in. Please see my code snippet below for fetchData. I will appreciate a pointer of how to include a header authorization with the token  in a snapshot segment of a collections.get(). I have tried every suggestion online with no luck. Thanks

```
//    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    try {
      final List<Product> loadedProducts = [];

      await _firestore
          .collection("products")
//          .get(headers: {HttpHeaders.authorizationHeader: '$authToken'}).then(
          .get()
          .then(
        (QuerySnapshot snapshot) {
          'Authorization: Bearer $authToken';
          if (snapshot != null) {
            snapshot.docs.forEach(
              (f) {
                loadedProducts.add(
                  Product(
                    id: f.id,
                    price: f.data()['price'],
                    title: f.data()['title'],
                    description: f.data()['description'],
                    imageUrl: f.data()['imageUrl'],
                    isFav: f.data()['isFav'],
                    category: f.data()['category'],
                    isSelected: f.data()['isSelected'],
                  ),
                );
              },
            );
          }
        },
      );
      _items = loadedProducts;
      notifyListeners();
    } catch (e) {
      throw e;
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear from your question how you sign the user in.

If you sign the user in by calling the Firebase Authentication SDK, then that sign-in information will automatically be passed along with database calls.

So: as long as your Firestore `get()` call happens after the sign-in completes with the Firebase Authentication SDK, the ID token will be passed along, and the `request.auth` variable in your security rules will reflect that.

Comment: I was signing user in using http request code and did verify user is logged in before going to the next screen where the product items from the database is retrieved. I get an error that user/caller has no permission to get data. When I relax the rules not to be tied to an authorized user, the data is retrieved implying maybe bcos idtoken wasn't included in the request. I know how to do this for http get but not collections.get

Comment: Making a HTTP request may give you a token, but you'll need to call a Firebase `signInWith...` method to sign that user into the Authentication client, so that it passes the ID token along with the requests to Firestore.